# SQlite data not showing up in device

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-emulator, data-retrieval

I am developing an application that fetches data from the SQLite database. I have the data in the tables. When i run the app in emulator it is fetching data properly. But when I tried debugging in a device no data is fetched. The cursor is returning 0 rows. Its working fine in emulator.

I have a button click event that trigger the database call and return a arraylist
the code snippet is as give below:

```
f4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                            f4.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(
                                    R.drawable.standards_btn_pressed));
                        } else {
                            f4.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.standards_btn_pressed));
                        }

                    List<ProductModel> pList = new ArrayList<ProductModel>();
                    db = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                    pList = db.getData("F4");
                    showTextFields(pList);

                }
            });

    //getData function

        public List<ProductModel> getData(String param) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String[] queryParam = new String[] { param.trim() };
            Cursor cursor=null;
            try
            {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(
                    "select * from FEPAFMACRO WHERE gritsize = ?", queryParam);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            List<ProductModel> pList = new ArrayList<ProductModel>();
            if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int i = 0;
                    do {
                        ProductModel pObj = new ProductModel();
                        pObj.gritSize = cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex("gritsize"));
                                .getColumnIndex("retention"));
                        pList.add(i, pObj);
                        i++;
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
            return pList;
        }
```

When I run this in emulator it is showing up data. But when i run in device no data is fetched. No error also. Nothing in Log report also

Comment: Post your some code please

Comment: Please share some code here....

Comment: added the code in the query. Thanks

Comment: Are you accessing your database from some folder or creating a through your application???